# Make Toolbar fixed to the bottom of a UITableView in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift, and I am struggling to find a solution: in my `UITableViewController`, I want to make a Toolbar that I have added to the storyboard fixed or "sticky" to the bottom of the view at all times.

Currently, after dragging a toolbar into the `UITableViewController`, it does add this toolbar; however, it places the toolbar as the final row of the table.

I want this toolbar to sit above the navigation tab bar at all times, making it fixed or sticky.

[image]

I have tried changing the View's content mode (by setting it to Bottom in the Storyboard) but it does not make a change in the UI.

Is there a way to set this programmatically to always show at the bottom and let the table scroll above it?

Comment: Actually you are stuck because of using subclass of `UITableViewController`. In this kind of subclassing, the table view occupies the whole viewable area of the view controller. You should be changing your base class to `UIViewController` and in the storyboard, drag a `UIViewController` object and then manually add the expected view as your need (i.e. `TableView`, `Toolbar`)

Answer (score 2):

```
//create a tool bar and add it in view
let toolbar = UIToolbar()
toolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(toolbar)
```

Set constraints to toolbar...

```
//top constraint to toolbar with tableview
self.toolbar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

//bottom constraint to toolbar with super view
self.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toolbar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

//leading constraint to toolbar with super view
self.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toolbar.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

//trailing constraint with toolbar with super view
self.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toolbar.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: It won't work on a subclass of `UITableViewController`.